# pdfBox convert pdf to image with transparency

Tags: java, pdfbox

This works fine so far, but how to add transparency to the generated images ?

```
for (img <- 0 until f.length) {
    val inputPdf = PDDocument.load(f(img).getPath).getDocumentCatalog.getAllPages.get(0).asInstanceOf[PDPage]

    val outputfile = new File(f(img).getName + ".png")
    ImageIO.write(inputPdf.convertToImage(), "png", outputfile)
}
```

Best regards
Torsten

Comment: You essentially render a PDF page to a bitmap image. But a PDF page is specified to have a white backdrop behind all painted stuff (when talking about transparency the specification generalizes a page **to a transparency group consisting of the entire stack of objects placed on the page, composited with a backdrop that is pure white and fully opaque**). Thus, when painting a whole page, the result does not have any transparency.

Comment: @mkl PDF seems to support transparency since 1.4.

Comment: @NiematojakTomasz Yes, internally it does when composing objects on a page, otherwise the notion of "transparency groups" above would make no sense after all. But a page as a final object is expected to be drawn on a white backdrop. (That is merely the specification, though, in your own renderer you can use a backdrop of your choice, including a fully transparent one. But this is the reason why you shouldn't expect existing PDF libraries to return transparent images when asked to draw a page.)

Comment: @mkl Assuming that you print on paper ;) PDF is currently being used widely for different purposes. But you are right. According to PDF you always print on one of specified color spaces and none of them supports transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [convertToImage(type, resolution)](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPage.html#convertToImage(int,%20int)) with [TYPE_INT_ARGB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB).

You can peek code of convertToImage: http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.4&path=/Source%20Packages/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel/PDPage.java (1.8.4) or https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/1.8.8/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPage.java (1.8.8-current)

```
public BufferedImage convertToImage() throws IOException
{
    //note we are doing twice as many pixels because
    //the default size is not really good resolution,
    //so create an image that is twice the size
    //and let the client scale it down.
    return convertToImage(8, 2 * DEFAULT_USER_SPACE_UNIT_DPI);
}
```

You probably want to use:

```
convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB, 2 * DEFAULT_USER_SPACE_UNIT_DPI);
```

NOTE: PDF support transparent object. However, as stated by @mkl it is not compatible with pdf reference.

Comment: That might indeed help; after all that `convertToImage(int,int)` overload initializes the background using `graphics.setBackground(TRANSPARENT_WHITE)` followed by a `clearRect` for the whole image area.

Comment: Fixes my problem. Thanks a lot.